# How to fix the problem of the page not showing after navigating (even if the navigation actually occures)

Tags: c#, maui

i was working on an application when , at some point , i needed to add a feature that allows the user to update a product . To do this i have a collection view of multiple products and with each product in this collection view there is a button that should allow the user to navigate to a page along with the informations of the sepcific product and update it there. but when i tried to do that , when i click the button nothing happens , so i tried to use debugging mode and what i found is that the navigation actually occures but the view somehow doesn't get updated (i mean by that that the app get stuck in the first page) , i think that this is a deadlock but i didn't know how to fix it
Here is the xaml code of the first page (that i navigate from ) :

```
 <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Products}"
                            SelectionMode="Single">
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Product">
                        <Border Stroke="#0b4c90"
                                StrokeThickness="1"
                                MinimumHeightRequest="100"
                                MaximumHeightRequest="100"
                                StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 20,20,20,20"
                                Margin="35,0,20,35"
                                BackgroundColor="#0b4c90"
                                Padding="7.5">
                            <Grid ColumnDefinitions=".7*,.3*">
                                <Grid RowDefinitions="*,*"
                                      RowSpacing="5">
                                    <HorizontalStackLayout Spacing="10">
                                        <Label Text="Product Id :"
                                               FontSize="25"
                                               TextColor="#FFF"/>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding Id}"
                                               FontSize="25"
                                               TextColor="#FFF"/>
                                    </HorizontalStackLayout>
                                    <HorizontalStackLayout Spacing="10"
                                                           Grid.Row="1">
                                        <Label Text="Product Name : "
                                               FontSize="25"
                                               TextColor="#FFF"/>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding ProductName}"
                                               FontSize="25"
                                               TextColor="#FFF"/>
                                    </HorizontalStackLayout>
                                </Grid>
                                <Grid Grid.Column="1"
                                      ColumnSpacing="5"
                                      ColumnDefinitions="*,*,*">
                                    <Button WidthRequest="50"
                                            HeightRequest="50"
                                            Text="&#xE811;"
                                            FontFamily="Icons"
                                            BackgroundColor="#FEE800"
                                            TextColor="#0B4C90"
                                            FontSize="25"
                                            Padding="0"
                                            Grid.Column="1"
                                            Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodel:ProductPageViewModel}}, Path=UpdateProductCommand}"
                                            CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
```

And here is the command i use to navigate :

```
public ICommand UpdateProductCommand => new Command<Product>(UpdateProduct);
public async void UpdateProduct(Product product)
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> query = new()
        {
            {nameof(Product), product }
        };
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(UpdateProductPage), query);
    }
```

and here is the UpdateProductPage.xaml.cs:

```
public UpdateProductPage(UpdateProductPageViewModel viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = viewModel;
    }
```

and here is the UpdateProductPageViewModel :

```
public partial class UpdateProductPageViewModel : ObservableObject, IQueryAttributable
{
   [ObservableProperty]
        Product product;

        public async void ApplyQueryAttributes(IDictionary<string, object> query)
        {
            Product = query[nameof(Product)] as Product;
            await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Test", $"{Product.Id}\n{Product.ProductName}\n", "Ok");
        }
}
```

and here's how i registered the routing for each one of those two pages :

```
Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(UpdateProductPage), typeof(UpdateProductPage));
Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(MainPage), typeof(MainPage));
```

I also tried looking for the solution in the net i found one that says that i should navigate using this command :

```
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(MainPage)}/{nameof(UpdateProductPageViewModel)}");
```

but it didn't work . And i found also a lot of similar solutions to this but they didn't work also .

Comment: Use the debugger to figure out where it hangs.  My first guess would be the DisplaySlert

Comment: @Jason i used it to figure out what happens . I put a breakpoint on the command that allows me to 'avigate and followed it all the way. It goes to the UpdateProductPage.xaml.cs , run the InitializeComponents method than goes to the viewmodel and runs the ApplyQueryAttributes , the Product variable gets filled then it seems to go to the display alert but i don't know if it actuallyexecute it or not because it jumps to the closing curly bracket and doesn't display anything

Comment: try commenting that line out

Comment: @Jason i did but it didn't work

Comment: I don't see anything else that would cause a hang.  I notice you didn't post the XAML for the page that is hanging.  All I can suggest is commenting out most of the code and XAML in the destination page/model, get it to display, and then add things back bit by bit until you find the problem

Comment: @Jason you were right the error was in the xaml code thank so much